# Laravel migration: Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `mediables` add primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations, mysql-error-1068

> **Error**: Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
> error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL:
> alter table `mediables` add primary key
> `mediables_media_id_mediable_type_mediable_id_tag_primary`(`media_id`,
> `mediable_type`, `mediable_id`, `tag`))

**my migration :**

```
  if (!Schema::hasTable('media')) {
            Schema::create(
                'media',
                function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->bigIncrements('id');
                    $table->string('disk', 32); 
                    $table->string('directory');
                    $table->string('filename');
                    $table->string('mime_type');
                    $table->string('aggregate_type');

                    $table->string('extension', 32); 
                    $table->integer('size')->nullable(false);
                    $table->timestamps(); 
                    $table->unique(['disk', 'directory', 'filename', 'extension']); 
                }
            );
        }

        if (!Schema::hasTable('mediables')) {
            Schema::create(
                'mediables',
                function (Blueprint $table) { 
                    $table->increments('media_id');
                    $table->string('mediable_type');
                    $table->integer('mediable_id')->unsigned();
                    $table->string('tag');
                    $table->integer('order')->unsigned(); 
                    $table->primary(['media_id', 'mediable_type', 'mediable_id', 'tag']);
                    $table->index(['mediable_id', 'mediable_type']);
                    $table->index('tag');
                    $table->index('order');
                    $table->foreign('media_id')
                        ->references('id')->on('media')
                        ->cascadeOnDelete();
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `increments` for foreign_key. Use `unsignedBigIntger` instead:

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('media')) {
            Schema::create(
                'media',
                function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->bigIncrements('id');
                    $table->string('disk', 32); 
                    $table->string('directory');
                    $table->string('filename');
                    $table->string('mime_type');
                    $table->string('aggregate_type');

                    $table->string('extension', 32); 
                    $table->integer('size')->nullable(false);
                    $table->timestamps(); 
                    $table->unique(['disk', 'directory', 'filename', 'extension']); 
                }
            );
        }

        if (!Schema::hasTable('mediables')) {
            Schema::create(
                'mediables',
                function (Blueprint $table) { 
                    $table->unsignedBigInteger('media_id');
                    $table->string('mediable_type');
                    $table->integer('mediable_id')->unsigned();
                    $table->string('tag');
                    $table->integer('order')->unsigned(); 
                    $table->primary(['media_id', 'mediable_type', 'mediable_id', 'tag']);
                    $table->index(['mediable_id', 'mediable_type']);
                    $table->index('tag');
                    $table->index('order');
                    $table->foreign('media_id')
                        ->references('id')->on('media')
                        ->cascadeOnDelete();
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `$table->increments('media_id');` creates an autoincrementing id column *and* a primary key. So your subsequent primary key declaration attempts to create another primary key, which is not allowed.

An autoincrementing id column does not have to be the primary key, but it must be an index.

Try this:

```php
    function (Blueprint $table) { 
      $table->increments('media_id');
      $table->string('mediable_type');
      $table->integer('mediable_id')->unsigned();
      $table->string('tag');
      $table->integer('order')->unsigned();

      /* create an index for the autoincrement column */
      $table->unique('media_id');  
      /* drop the primary key */
      $table->dropPrimary(); 
      /* add your new primary key */
      $table->primary(['media_id', 'mediable_type', 'mediable_id', 'tag']);

      $table->index(['mediable_id', 'mediable_type']);
      $table->index('tag');
      $table->index('order');
      $table->foreign('media_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('media')
                  ->cascadeOnDelete();
  }
```

I haven't tested this however.

If you can't get Laravel to cooperate with using a different PK than the autoincrement column, you may have to use an ordinary index. You can alter the indexes later with SQL statements if you really need your compound primary key.  Something like this should work.

```
ALTER TABLE mediables 
     ADD UNIQUE INDEX media_id (media_id),
     DROP PRIMARY KEY,
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (media_id, mediable_type, mediable_id, tag);
```

Do this all in one statement.

Because your new primary key starts with the autoincrementing column, you actually can omit the UNIQUE index, giving

```
ALTER TABLE mediables 
     DROP PRIMARY KEY,
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (media_id, mediable_type, mediable_id, tag);
```

Comment: Why would he use media_id  foreign key as autoincrement?

Comment: I don't know. That's a question for the original questioner, not me. I'm trying to answer the question as written.